# Imageview no respeta las dimensiones en celular

Tags: android, android-imageview

Buenas Tardes

El problema que tengo es que la imagen no respeta el tamaño correcto en un dispositivo, esto se debe adaptar por cada tipo de resolución

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/White"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnTomaFoto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_style"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/camera"
    android:text="@string/strTomarFoto" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    >
</ImageView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ly1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMuestraFoto"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_style"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"
        android:text="@string/strMuestraFoto" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEnviar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_style"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/check"
        android:text="@string/strEnviar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Y cuando tomo una foto, la imagen me la amplia demasiado, como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Captura de pantalla con imagen ancha]

La imagen se debe adaptar a diferentes resoluciones de equipos; en el celular que estoy probando, tengo los siguientes resultados en base a las siguientes lineas de codigo:

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;

    Log.d("debug", "width: " + width); // 480
    Log.d("debug", "height: " + height); // 800

    Log.d("debug", "screen: " + getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout); // 98
    Log.d("debug", "mask: " + Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK); // 15

    Log.d("debug", "large: " + Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE); // 3
    Log.d("debug", "normal: " + Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL); // 2
    Log.d("debug", "small: " + Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL); // 1
```

Y la salida:

> width: 480
>   height: 800
>   screen: 98
>   mask: 15

Y finalmente asi es como muestro la imagen en el imageview:

```
int bitmapHeight = bMap.getHeight();
int bitmapWidth = bMap.getWidth();
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(rotacion);
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, matrix, false);

Bitmap tamanio = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(rotatedBitmap, bitmapHeight / 6, bitmapWidth / 6, false);

img.setImageBitmap(tamanio);
```

Comment: porque no pones para cada resolucion , la altura y ancho dinamicamente por codigo ?

Comment: porque no cambias el atributo scaleType del ImageView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uno de los grandes problemas al desarrollar aplicaciones en android es la gran diversidad de tamaños de pantalla que se tienen. Lo que intentas hacer que, segun entiendo, es re dimensionar la imagen de manera programatica no me parece la solucion mas optima debido a que luce como demasiado trabajo y demasiado codigo que no aporta mucho. La solucion que te propongo es cambiar la propiedad scaleType del image view de la siguiente manera.

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imgView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
>
```

Con esta propiedad lo que logras es que la imagen que se muestre en el imageView se redimensione de tal forma que se muestre la mayor cantidad de imagen posible sin deformar la misma. Esta es la mejor practica y la solución a tu problema en mi opinión.